# Why did this Shadowcash question get downvoted to -5?

Tags: discussion

I think the question is relevant, was the answer incorrect?

[How was the faulty ShadowCash implementation of ring signatures repaired in February 2016?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-was-the-faulty-shadowcash-implementation-of-ring-signatures-repaired-in-febr?rq=1)

In particular, questions like this will keep popping up:
[How does ShadowCash compare to Monero?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/how-does-shadowcash-compare-to-monero)

Answer (score 2):

I downvoted this [one](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/how-does-shadowcash-compare-to-monero) too, it was my understanding that only other [CryptoNote coins are allowed](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-considered-off-topic). Also I dont think Shen Noether fixed the SDC implementation but cracked it.

Comment: You are right that Shen cracked the implementation. AFAIK he was not involved in fixing it. The wording of the question is still not ideal because AFAIK nobody from Monero helped repair.  Therefore it may not be possible to confirm how (or if) it was properly repaired.

Comment: thats why we should keep the stack clean of unrelated coins, its not the community's job to answer these questions imo.

Comment: I agree that detailed questions about other currencies should be limited to  direct comparison with Monero, unless the coin being asked about is also based on CryptoNote. Shadowcash may be a gray area because although based on Bitcoin, it does use ring signatures.

Comment: Perhaps the question could be edited to ask how Shen broke the ring signature implementation. That we would be able to answer unlike the current question asking how (or if) it was properly fixed.

Comment: I think it's inevitable that people will come here, the authoritative source of Monero information, to ask "how does Monero compare to X" and we should have canonical answers to those questions. I also think it's important when we say "X has thus-and-such flaw" to have ready proof/documentation of those flaws.

Comment: @hyc In this specific example do you think asking how the faulty ShadowCash implementation of ring signatures was repaired is on topic?

Comment: After some reflection I agree with @5chdn that this question is off topic. Questions about how broken ring signature implementations were dealt with by Bitcoin PoW/PoS hybrids are not really within the score of this stack.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the downvotes for the [first question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-was-the-faulty-shadowcash-implementation-of-ring-signatures-repaired-in-febr?rq=1) came prior to the edits that improved its wording (original question shown below):

> How Shen Noether fixed the implementation of ring signatures?
>
> From the technical perspective, how Shen Noether fixed the implementation of ring signatures which were originally implemented incorrectly resulting in a partial de-anonymization of ShadowCash? What was the fix?

An edit to the [current answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/129/11) of first question may be appropriate now as it was made when the wording of the question was much different than today.

The [second](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/how-does-shadowcash-compare-to-monero) question is not worded as well as the current [DASH](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/112/how-is-monero-compared-to-dash), [Bitcoin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-monero-and-bitcoin) And [Zcash](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/83/how-does-monero-privacy-and-security-compare-to-zcash) comparison questions because of the speculative "why" part of the question question?

> why is it that ShadowCash is at number 41 in market cap and Monero and Dash take places in top 10

I just edited out that part question, so that an answer can just focus on the technical differences (PoW vs. PoS, implementation differences, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The question was originally written in a misleading way , and several changes made after comments made to correct the problems kept being misleading. I have no idea whether it was meant to be misleading or not, but the difficulty in getting the question to not be was probably what triggered those votes.