# ShadowCash (SDC): Is it on topic?

Tags: discussion

After seeing [this question](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-did-this-shadowcash-question-get-downvoted-to-5), I believe we need to come to a decision as to whether SDC is a valid topic on the Monero StackExchange. While SDC is on a Bitcoin codebase (and not CryptoNote), it does use Ring Signatures, which makes it (in my mind) at least partially on topic here. I personally don't own or care about Shadowcash, but I think it would be best if we made a general policy decision as to whether it's on or off topic here, before any more SDC questions get asked.

Answer (score 5):

Questions that touch Monero or Cryptonote are on topic. If a question is about ring signatures as a whole, or comparison between ring signatures in Monero and SDC, then it's on topic. If the question is specifically about SDC, then it's not. It'd be better in the Bitcoin SE in the first place, especially since it is a de facto default SE for other cryptos AFAICT. SDC is irrelevant, what is relevant is whether there is a link, whether strong or weak, to Monero or Cryptonote.

Answer (score 4):

I expect we will continue to get "How does X compare to Monero" questions. And I believe we should have good answers to those questions, here. Of course, the bulk of content can live elsewhere, we don't need to be an encyclopedia of broken anon-coin wannabes.

Comment: This is an important question and I agree with you opinion that Monero comparisons should be allowed. It seems there is more disagreement about your other question where instead of a comparison with Monero, the issue was how another coin fixed its broken ring signature implementation.  http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-did-this-shadowcash-question-get-downvoted-to-5

Comment: what about this one? http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/how-does-nav-coin-compare-to-monero 
The SDC one was allowed and this one not. I believe there should be a clear policy. I guess nobody wanted to bother checking up NAV to give an answer there, although it could probably be answered in a few bullet points.

Comment: @JollyMort Since NAV used a closed source privacy system a proper comparison is technically impossible. AFAIK they also do not use ring signatures (like SDC) so the situation seems a little bit different to me.