# Benefit of "Monero compared to X" questions

Tags: discussion

Is there any benefit to the "How does Monero compare to X coin" questions that keep popping up? For example:

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/how-is-monero-different-than-ethereum

https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/does-monero-offer-any-technical-advantages-over-zcash

[What is the Bikercoin currency?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/what-is-the-bikercoin-currency)

[How does ShadowCash compare to Monero?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/how-does-shadowcash-compare-to-monero)

There are others but you get the idea. I know there is the `cryptocurrency-comparison` tag but do these comparisons help, or just distract from better, more related questions?

Answer (score 4):

Questions about other CryptoNote coins are [on topic](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-on-topic).

[Bikercoin](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/what-is-the-bikercoin-currency) apparently is a CryptoNote coin so should be considered on topic, although I think the question should be worded in a better manner to narrow its focus.

Since SDC uses ring signatures, it [may](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/shadowcash-sdc-is-it-on-topic) be on topic if the questions focuses on ring signatures or a ring signature related comparison with Monero. General SDC questions (which is a PoS coin based on the Bitcoin blockchain, not a PoW based CryptoNote currency like Monero) are clearly off topic.

Comparisons with other major coins with a SE presence (such as BTC and ETH) are also likely to continue. I closed the ETH question you cited in your question not because of ETH but because the question was far too broad. Comparison questions should be as narrowly focused as possible.

Those focused on privacy are likely to come here with technical questions related to how Monero and Zcash compare. Zcash comparison (with Monero) questions should also be allowed provided they are narrowly focused enough to make an objective answer possible. General Zcash questions (not related to Monero) clearly should be off topic.

Answer (score 4):

In general it's not of a good style to ask questions about comparing technologies and I would suggest everyone to avoid doing so.

However, due to their nature, these questions are limited in overall amount and most likely wont get asked in the future, so we can tolerate them and use them as canonical reference if future duplicates are created.

There wont be 10 questions comparing Darkcoin to Monero, but only one. And maybe one more for each other currency to compare. That's acceptable on a site where usually thousends of quetions will be asked.

Comment: "these questions are limited in overall amount and most likely wont get asked in the future" - if no one will ask them in the future, why bother keeping them? This is supposed to be a place for useful posts to be collected.

Comment: I think what he was trying to say was that once this question is asked about a certain cryptocurrency, no more of these questions about that currency need to be asked because it has already been answered. At least, that is how I read it.

Comment: They are useful questions, though whether they can get a useful and unbiased answer is not a given. If they can, I think they belong here.