# Is there a need for Legacy CryptoNote tag preservation?

Tags: discussion

Monero has now abandoned some of the legacy CryptoNote terminolgy it inherited.

As a result some [new master tags](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) were created. As an example `monero-wallet-cli` has replaced `simplewallet` in Monero v0.10.0 - Wolfram Warptangent.

My inclination would be to merge these tags as we already did with `monerod` when it replaced `bitmonerod`

Are there any objections to such a tag merger on the basis of `simplewallet` (or other legacy tags) still being used by other CryptoNote forks that are [on topic](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-considered-off-topic) on Stack Exchange

Currently most questions about other CryptoNote currencies (which are small in number) are comparison questions (with Monero) so I don't expect most legacy CryptoNote tags to be heavily used should they be preserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I support merging old tags to reflect the current names used by Monero.

Keeping old tag names purely for the benefit of other CryptoNote projects that may still use them seems unnecessary and may increase confusion about current Monero terminology.

Comment: I agree, Monero's current codebase bears little resemblance to CryptoNote.

Answer (score 4):

The great majority of questions here are about Monero. I think one specific tag such as `aeon` or `boolberry` is sufficient for other CryptoNote forks and there is no need to have other CryptoNote tags for terms no longer used by Monero.